# Запуск программ от админа без прав админа

Tags: windows, администрирование, users

Имеются много учётных записей объединённых в группу `usersgroup` с правами обычного пользователя. Им нужно запускать программы которые требуют права Администратора, но назначать их в группу Администраторов не желательно.
Как сделать так, что бы они могли запускать программы от имени администратора без прав администратора??
Программы типа runas, AdmiLink и т.п не подходят, потому что они разрешают запускать программы от имени администратора без прав под конкретной учётной записью, а мне нужно для группы учётных записей так как учёток очень много.

Comment: Какая версия windows?

Comment: Подойдет ли [Sudo for windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/) ?Пользователей просто нужно запихать в локальную группу Sudoers.

Answer (score 2):

Понимаю что некропостинг, но больно уж чудная задачка (ставьте ударение куда хотите %) ).

По отсылке к большой группе учёток, можно допустить, что речь идет о доменных пользователях.

В принципе, в случаях, когда доменному пользователю нужны права администратора для некоторого рабочего набора программ, его проще всего поместить в группу "Локальные администраторы" конкретной рабочей станции. Таким образом, пользователь сможет навредить только своему компьютеру и почти(!) не способен навредить домену в целом.

Если такой вариант никак не подходит, то нужно внимательно изучить для чего программы требуют повышенные привилегии, возможно для этого не требуются полные административные права, а только конкретные, тогда можно подобрать более подходящую группу узкоспециализированных администраторов.

Чаще всего требование повышенных привилегий связано с записью на диск в защищаемые системой папки, вроде Program Files или корень системного диска. Обычно это касается старых программ. В таком случае можно настроить права папки в которую установлена программа, чтобы в нее могли писать обычные пользователи.

Если повышение прав связано с записью в системную ветку реестра или вызов системных функций, требующих повышенных привилегий, для которых не существует преднастроенных узкоспециализированных групп, то так просто уже не решается, и вариантов не так чтобы много.

**Плохой вариант** - создать BAT-файл, в котором прописать запуск от имени локального администратора. Плохой он тем, что BAT-файл это обычный текст и вы собственноручно сообщаете пользователю учетные данные локального администратора. При этом выдать права локального администратора явно - проще и более безопасно, т.к. их в нужный момент можно и отобрать.

**Плохой и сложный способ** - написать к каждой программе лаунчер, который будет запускать программу в отдельном процессе от имени нужного пользователя. Проблема заключается в том, что лаунчер должен каким либо способом получать данные нужной учетной записи для запуска процесса, а то это в целом не слишком отличает данный способ от BAT-файла по надежности и безопасности, зато на несколько порядков сложнее в реализации.

**Неудобный вариант 1** - с помощью системного планировщика задач можно запускать указанные программы автоматически, например при логине пользователя. Да, в планировщике необходимо будет указать от чьего имени должна быть запущена программа, но эти данные не хранятся в открытом виде и получить их будет существенно сложнее (если вообще возможно, т.к. планировщик работает с системными правами и значит ему нужен только дескриптор пользователя, а его логин и пароль ему без надобности, но это только теория, глубоко не копал). Минусы данного подхода в том, что настройку нужно делать на конкретных рабочих станциях индивидуально и если пользователь закроет программу, то заново запустить ее он не сможет, для этого ему потребуется выйти из системы и зайти снова. К тому же, если мне не изменяет память, системный планировщик не умеет различать какой именно пользователь залогинился.

**Неудобный вариант 2** - использовать logon-скрипты в групповой политике. С одной стороны все здорово, мы просто молча запускаем программу при логине пользователя обычным BAT-файлом и не раскрываем информацию о его содержимом (во всяком случае необходимо обладать некоторой квалификацией чтобы ее получить, а если пользователь обладает необходимой квалификацией - ему проще дать локального администратора). С другой стороны имеем часть недостатков из **Неудобный вариант 1** и необходимость разместить учетки пользователей в одном OU в Active Directory, для применения групповой политики только к этим пользователям.

Comment: Спасибо за некроответ :))), полезный. +1

Answer (score -2):

**Как изменить владельца файла либо папки**

- Щелкните на файле либо папке правой кнопкой мыши и выберите команду
     Свойства, после чего откройте вкладку Безопасность.
- Щелкните на кнопке Дополнительно.  Откроется вкладка Владелец.
- Щелкните на кнопке Изменить и откроется окно Дополнительные параметры
  безопасности. Теперь выберите нужного пользователя либо группу в
  списке Изменить владельца на и щелкните на кнопке ОК.
- Предположим, что нужного пользователя или группы в списке не
  оказалось. Щелкните на кнопке Другие пользователи и группы. Теперь в
  поле Введите имена выбираемых объектов введите имя пользователя либо
  группы.
- Введите имена выбираемых объектов.Однако, вводить имя следует по специальным правилам, узнать которые можно, щелкнув на ссылке примеры.

Есть вариант и проще

- щелкните на кнопке Дополнительно и затем на кнопке Поиск. В окне
  Результаты поиска будут найдены все пользователи и группы на вашем
  компьютере.
- Осталось выбрать пользователя или группу и щелкнуть на кнопке ОК. Мы
  вернемся в предыдущее окно, где будет указан выбранный нами
  пользователь.
- Щелкните на кнопке ОК. Теперь главное – установите флажок Заменить
  владельца подконтейнеров и объектов, после чего щелкните на кнопке
  ОК. В результате, папка или файл получат нового владельца.
- Заменить владельца подконтейнеров и объектов

**Как изменить разрешения доступа к файлам или папкам**

Ладно, с владельцами разобрались. Как насчет разрешений доступа? Вот добавили мы нового владельца, однако, что если необходимо указать, что именно разрешено ему делать, а для чего пусть губу не раскатывает? Сделать это можно тоже с помощью вкладки Безопасность.

- Щелкните правой кнопкой на файле или папке и выберите команду
  Свойства, затем перейдите на вкладку Безопасность. Выберите в поле
  Группы или пользователи нужного пользователя/группу и щелкните на
  кнопке Изменить.
- Теперь в столбце Разрешить и Запретить установите нужные флажки
  напротив тех разрешений, что вам требуются. Скажем, если нужно
  запретить пользователю изменение файлов либо папок, поставьте флажок
  в столбце Запретить напротив разрешения Изменение. Затем щелкните на
  кнопке Применить и запрет вступит в силу.
- Если же нужного пользователя в списке не оказалось, щелкните на
  кнопке Добавить. Откроется уже знакомое нам окно, в котором можно
  добавить нужного пользователя. О том, как это сделать, написано в
  предыдущем подразделе.

К слову сказать, в окне Разрешения можно без проблем удалить пользователя или группу, для чего достаточно щелкнуть на кнопке Удалить.

Comment: Эм.. А как это относится к вопросу?